# Could not resolve './globalThis.js' in vite, graphql, react build

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, vite

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkgBj.png)

When I am try to vite build my react app then occure this error. I build react app with vite.

```
vite.config.js contains
 return defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    define: {
      global: "globalThis"
    },
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem solution.
Basically, if you create your react app by vite then must be defined in vite.config.js like

```
define: {
  globalThis: 'window'
},
```

I was face this problem for install graphql
to solve this issue in vite.config.js

```
plugins: [react(), graphql],
define: {
  globalThis: 'window'
},
```

If do not run or start react project simply define

```
   define: {
      global: 'globalThis',
   },
```